# DisplayAlert in Xamarin when page first opens

Tags: c#, xamarin

my application page where I want the display alert to appear is when the page is first loaded. The page is using `StackLayout` controls and several buttons on the page.

```
DisplayAlert("Question?", "Heave you entered your information before", "Yes", "No");
```

That is what I currently have but it is not displaying. Do I need to include it into the layout children or something along those lines thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it when your page loads, place it in the `OnAppearing` method

```
protected async override void OnAppearing ()
{
  base.OnAppearing ();

  // any other initialization code goes here

  await DisplayAlert("Question?", "Have you entered your information before?", "Yes", "No");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying with an answer. Ahh that is how you do a OnAppearing, I will try that I tell if you it works or not. Thank You again

Comment: Ok this worked thank you both for answering my question